# System.DllNotFoundException: msmpi.dll not found on OS X

Tags: c#, macos, mpi

I wanted to run an example using C# and MPI.NET (https://github.com/mpidotnet/MPI.NET).
I found some sources on StackOverflow that I should install open-mpi via homebrew. I did this.
I also have Mono installed, and after building the project with msbuild, I try to run Hello.exe with the following command:

```
mpiexec -np 2 mono Hello.exe
```

I get the exception `System.DllNotFoundException: msmpi.dll assembly`, which is straightforward. The problem is I don't know where to find this DLL, or whether some other mistake might be causing it.

Comment: Try doing `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono Hello.exe`

Comment: The error message suggests you should Microsoft MPI is not  installed. Not sure you should expect this to work on OS X though.